# 'absl/base/config.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Currently running Xcode 12 Beta-3 I am getting the below error;

[image: Xcode-error]

I have the following pods installed;

- pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
- pod 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
- pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'

With all pods set to deployment iOS 14.0

My question is where do I find this file "abs/base/config.h" and how do I add it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rolling back to a previous version of the Firebase Cocoapods.

- pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.2.0'
- pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.2.0'
- pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '6.2.0'